# ipyparallel Parallel for loop that appends to list

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython-parallel

I have a loop which does a bunch of CPU intensive calculations and appends the result to a list, per iteration.

How can I have that working in parallel. On C# there are concurrent containers, how does it work in ipyparallel?

From the ipyparallel documentation:

> Python’s builtin map() functions allows a function to be applied to a sequence element-by-element. This type of code is typically trivial to parallelize.

http://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/direct.html#parallel-map

So it's a matter of using the map function to have it running on parallel, but how can I append the results to a list? Are there concurrent containers here?

So, what I have now is something like this:

```
results = []
for element in list:
    outcome = very_heavy_computation_function(element)
    results.append(outcome)
```

How can I do this in parallel?

Comment: Have a look at the python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrency.html. Your questions are probably too broad SO. If you have a specific issue, feel free to ask.

Comment: My question isn't too broad. Thank you for the link to the python docs. I want to append an element to a list that is being populated on a for loop. I think it may be one of the most trivial types of chunks to parallelize. Will update my question with more details though, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it in the following way.

Function `foo` represents calculations in the loop, `parameters` represents the data you want to iterate over if any. Even though `foo` sleeps for 10s the whole loop takes exactly 10s instead of 40s because I have 4 engines in my environment and functions run parallelly on the engines. A LoadBalancedView provides dynamic load balancing to evenly distribute work among engines.

```
from ipyparallel import Client

rc = Client()
view = rc.load_balanced_view()

def foo(param):
    import time
    time.sleep(10)
    return param*2

parameters = list(range(4))
async_results = []
for p in parameters:
    async_result = view.apply_async(foo, p)
    async_results.append(async_result)

rc.wait_interactive(async_results)

results = [ar.get() for ar in async_results]
print(results)
```

Output:

```
   4/4 tasks finished after   10 s
done
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: I've got terrible scoping problems when I attempt to employ this example. Whenever I try to reference variables I get 'is not defined' errors. Ugh.